# Pass form login data to another frameset page

Tags: html, frames

I have a webpage 1 that has a login form on it, like this

```
<form method="post" action="webpage2" name="login">
    <fieldset><span class="graytitle">Big Fields</span>
    <ul class="pageitem">
        <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Username" name="id"/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" /></li>
                                <li class="button">
        <input name="Submit input" type="submit" value="Submit input" />

        </li>
    </ul>
        </fieldset></form>
```

Then I have a webpage2 which is a frameset of a webpage3 which should acquire the data from webpage1.

```
 <frameset cols='100%'><frameset
 rows='100%'><frame
 src='webpage3.html'></frameset></frameset>
```

How can I pass the login data to webpage3 which is in a frame of webpage2?

I need it to be like the above scenario with frames. I cannot post directly to webpage3 as I will be adding some addition code to webpage2

THank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. IIf `webpage1` were in a frame of `webpage2`, then you could use the `target` attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="webpage2" name="login" target="name_of_other_frame">

<frame name="name_of_other_frame" src......
```

but that's about it I think.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be secure, you can put the login into your iframes src (querystring), like:

```
<iframe src="webpage3.html?username=something&password=something"..
```

You'd have to insert those values, but pretty simple.

Edit note:  You could encrypt/encode that data before inserting it, for more security too